# Как отслеживать нажатие мыши на 2д картинку в unity?

Tags: unity3d

Нужна не кнопка, а именно картинка. Можно отслеживать на неё нажатия? Добавил BoxCollider2d, пробывал отслеживать через метод OnMouseDown. Как я понимаю, он не работает на 2д объектах. Вот мой код картинки:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class Click : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log("+");
    }
}
```

Я новичок, помогите пожалуйста. Просмотрел много сайтов и, так не понял...

Comment: Понял, что команда работает на 2д объекты, но возможно ли это сделать на UI объекты?

Comment: Physics2D.queriesHitTriggers должен быть true. На объекте должен быть коллайдер-триггер.

Answer (score 0):

Добавь на картинку метод Button через AddComponent, и она будет у тебя как кнопка, но картинка

Comment: Этот ответ был бы более полезен, если бы был подкреплен примером кода :)

Comment: Тут как бы даже кодить не надо